# Проверка форматирования кода

Tags: c++, format

Хочу организовать проверку форматирования кода на стороне `ci` с помощью `clang-format` и опции `-output-replacements-xml`. Задумка была такая: если файл не отформатирован, то `clang-format` выдаст об этом информацию (тэг `replacements`), а раз таковой имеется, то файл не был отформатирован. Но тут возникла проблема: даже при отформатированном файле `clang-format` выдает ненулевой вывод (ругается на инклюды):

clang-format-8

файл:

```
// my_sample.h
#pragma once

#include "my_header.h"
```

запуск `clang-format`:

```
clang-format -style=file logger.hpp -output-replacements-xml
```

вывод:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<replacements xml:space='preserve' incomplete_format='false'>
<replacement offset='30' length='24'>#include "my_header.h"&#10;</replacement>
</replacements>
```

Почему так? Как правильно организовать проверку форматирования?

Comment: `#include "my_header.h"` - 22 символа. Такое ощущение, что он пытается заменить CRLF на LF. Что если заранее убрать все CR из файла?

Comment: это *nix, так что сдесь только LF

Comment: Какой-то символ он точно убирает. Может в конце строки пробел? Я бы hex-редактором посмотрел.

Comment: проблема ведь в том, что этот файл уже отформатирован, но, несмотря на это, он все равно требует нового форматирования...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, прочитайте внимательнее сообщения HolyBlackCat - у Вас 22 символа в строке, 23-ий должен быть концом строки. Но в репорте указано 24 символа.

Comment: @isnullxbh вы тоже внимательно посмотрите на то, что писал я, а именно: файл уже отфарматирован через clang-format. Также это *nix система - почему пишет на 1 символ больше - не имею ни малейшего понятия

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я хотел акцентировать Ваше внимание на том, что  что говорит HolyBlackCat: пусть его комментарий и не решает Вашей проблемы, но он раскрывает новые детали (не упомянутые в самом вопросе) - а это открывает новые горизонты для поиска.